# How to use a variable declared inside a class, outside of this class?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I've got this problem with a project that involves programming in Python.
I made this class with which a screen pops up and so allowing me to open a xls file.
Inside this class the directory to this file is then put into this variable 'filename'. :>

```
class OpenFile(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(OpenFile, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    openFile = QtGui.QPushButton('Open Orderpakket', self)
    openFile.setGeometry(0, 00, 350, 300)
    openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
    self.connect(openFile, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.showDialog)
    self.setWindowTitle('Open Orderpakket')

  def showDialog(self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',r'J:\Integratie Project\Files', "Excel Files (*.xls*.xlsx)")

    print filename
```

Inside this class the variable filename indeed has the correct directory inside it.
Now i want to use it here, outsite a class or a def:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)
```

That doesn't work, giving me the error that 'filename is not defined'

I've read about the 'global' command of Python which seems to have the solution, but i can't seem to get that working.

Anyone?

Comment: Python has no concept of "declaration".  Variables are not "declared".  Please fix your title to describe what you're **really** doing.  You're failing to use `self` to create an instance variable.  Your title might be something like "How can I careate an instance variable without using `self`", since that might be what your code is attempting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will not get into details of your code, but will use it only to explain the basic concepts.

The variable `filename` in `showDialog` is defined as a local variable - hence, you cannot access it outside this function.

If you want to define the variable as an instance variable for the class OpenFile, you need to use `self.filename`.

I assume you have somewhere an instance of the class `OpenFile`, such as:

```
openfile = OpenFile()
```

Now you can access the variable from this instance by invoking:

```
openfile.filename
```

Comment: Thx for your quick comment!
It works now and it also simplifies some of my other coding aswell.
Happy with your answer :-D 
Wouldn't have thought my problem was actually this smimple.

Comment: Great to hear. As you saw, the better you formalize your problem, the quicker you get answers -- this problem was very well posed. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

Add `filename` as an attribute to the object of your class, i.e. `self`:

```
self.filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',r'J:\Integratie Project\Files', "Excel Files (*.xls *.xlsx)")
```

This way you can access it like that:

```
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(openfile.filename)
```

where `openfile` is an object of `OpenFile` class.

Comment: Thx for your answer aswell! I like the speed with which you answered!